# Найти и заменить запись, если есть

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, update, выборка

Есть в наличии массив

```
$parts(
{'name'=>'name1','stock'=>1,'contractor'=>2},{'name'=>'name2','stock'=>3,'contractor'=>1}
{...})
```

и таблица

```
_parts (id, name, stock,contractor)
```

Требуется перебрать массив, и по нескольким его свойствам найти и апдейтить запись в таблице, либо вставить новую запись, если ничего не найдено.

Легко можно сделать это за два запроса, но данный вариант прям нежелателен (перебираться будет довольно большой массив).
Так как свойств несколько, то, насколько я понял, функция INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE тоже нельзя использовать.

Поделитесь мыслями.

Comment: `on duplicate` работает с любым количеством свойств. главное, что бы на таблице был уникальный ключ или индекс по тем полям которые должны быть уникальны (по которым обнаруживается "дублирование").  Обратите внимание: ключ или индекс _может_ включать сразу несколько колонок

Comment: @Mike А могу ли я использовать INDEX для VARCHAR поля? И еще, в таблице поле-ключ - id. С него нужно ключ снять?

Comment: id может и должен оставаться первичным ключом, на второе уникальное само по себе поле спокойно делайте уникальный индекс и да, конечно он может быть на varchar (`create unique index parts_name on _parts(name)` например)

Comment: @Mike Попробовал конструкцию `INSERT INTO #__parts (partnumber,stock,brand) VALUES ( ' . $db_net->quote($local_part->partnumber) . ',' . $local_part->stock . ',' . $local_part->brand . ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = ' . $local_part->quantity` (перед этим в таблице отметил нужные поля как индексы). Добавляет новые записи даже при наличии идентичной.

Comment: Разобрался. Эти поля должны быть UNIQUE

Comment: @Mike Еще вопрос туда же - функция работает по OR принципу, получается. То есть если хотя бы один из ключей совпадает, по производится апдейт? У меня сейчас так и происходит

Comment: Если индксов несколько, то конечно, любой из них не позволит вставить дубль и будет update. Если же нужно что бы уникальной была связка из нескольких полей - то и делайте один уникальный индекс, содержащий несколько полей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена с помощью @Mike

В таблице _parts создана связка из нескольких индексов:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_array ON _parts(name,stock)
```

Теперь, перебирая массив, каждую запись проверяем на наличие, UPDATE при дублировании обоих полей, INSERT при отсутствии дубля хотя бы одного.

```
INSERT INTO _parts (name,stock,contractor,quantity) VALUES('partname',stockId,contractorId, partQuantity) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = NewPartQuantity
```